# Saying about good and bad

Tags: expressions, quotes, popular-refrains

Is there a saying or a quote, when something good happen thanks to something bad ? Like you meet someone because you've lost someone else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Blessing in disguise* means something apparently bad turned out for good. For instance, a chest x-ray to diagnose pneumonia, in which a tumor was also seen, in time for life-saving surgery. The pneumonia was a *blessing in* [the] *disguise* of illness.

*Every cloud has a silver lining* is originally a paraphrase of a Bible proverb. It has the meaning that something is not altogether bad, it also has some good aspect.

*Every catastrophe brings a small gift.* This may be a translation from a Greek folk saying.  A woman over forty years old was divorcing, and her emotional state suppressed her appetite.  She became as slim as she was twenty years earlier. *Catastrophe* was the divorce, the *small gift* was her new slim figure.

Answer (score 0):

One popular idiom is [*every cloud has a silver lining*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/every_cloud_has_a_silver_lining#English):

> In every bad situation there is an element of good

Another one would be "[when/where/as] one door closes, another opens", attributed to [Alexander Graham Bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Graham_Bell).

For more options still, see [What is the English equivalent to the Chinese/Japanese saying, “塞翁失馬— The life is like Old Sai’s horse”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199859/what-is-the-english-equivalent-to-the-chinese-japanese-saying-%E5%A1%9E%E7%BF%81%E5%A4%B1%E9%A6%AC-the-life-i)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this answer- these are the two I immediately thought of. +1